# What is the >> operator really doing in this C++ code?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I am following along with *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++*, and I am messing with the "get from" (`>>`) operator from some code in the third chapter. Here is a minimal reproducible version.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int first_num;
    int second_num;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> first_num;
    first_num >> second_num;
    cout << "second_num is now: " << second_num;
}
```

The output that I got was the following:

```
Enter a number: 12  
second_num is now: 4201200
```

I had thought that second_num would just get the value of first_num, but clearly not. What has happened here? I am assuming this is defaulting to a bitshift rather than the "get from" operator, but if second_num is not defined, how does the computer know how far to bit shift first_num?

Comment: _"get from" (>>) operator_ Is that new? Never heard of it. Nm. I guess you meant extraction operator.

Comment: You are UB (undefined behavior). `second_num` is not initialized.

Comment: In your case you used `>>` as a bit-shifting operator, and actually you don't assign the result of this operator anywhere, so `first_num >> second_num;` practically does nothing. `second_num` remains uninitialized, and `4201200` is just a meaningless "uninitialized" number

Comment: Any attempt to guess what the appropriate C++ syntax is, for a given operation, is highly likely to end in a dismal failure. Even if the resulting code is syntactically valid, and compiles, the end results may be quite surprising.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Its what Bjarne calls it in the third chapter of his book, I guess it probably has a more formal name 

Comment: @RyanFolks Ok, that makes sense. I've always heard it called "extraction operator". I thought maybe they added another use for the ">>" operator.

Comment: You will learn later (Chapter 10) that you can write your own `operator>>` to do just about anything you want. The standard library is full of those, and you cannot find out everything they do by just testing random code. So continue reading the book!  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because you bitshift using `second_num` which is not initialized.

```
first_num >> second_num  // right shift `second_num` bits
```

Note that the operator `>>` you use above is not the same as the overload used to extract a value from `std::cin`.

Comment: I am coming from Python, so please excuse the ignorance, but why does second_num even have a valid value at all? Why isn't an error being thrown?

Comment: @RyanFolks You'd probably get a warning about using `second_num` which is uninitialized if you turn on more warning options when compiling. You'd probably also get a warning about the fact that you are not storing the result of the bitshift anywhere. It's not a valid value. Reading `second_num` makes the program have undefined behavior so anything could happen. It could crash or erase files on disk etc - or just print the value that happened to be in the memory location where `second_num` resides.

Comment: @RyanFolks here is your code [with compiler warnings turned on](https://godbolt.org/z/E377ajT6h).  It would benefit you to find out how to turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: @RyanFolks *Why isn't an error being thrown?* -- Because that is not the design of C++.  Error checking means extra code generated by the compiler, which means slower programs.  If you want to check for errors, you need to do it explicitly.  There is no hand-holding with C++.  You want to use a variable not initialized, go right ahead -- the problem is that we cannot predict how your program will behave.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the help. Couldn't this be used to accidentally overwrite or even steal system data directly from memory that a program shouldn't have access to?

Comment: @RyanFolks -- `char a[10]; cin >> a;` -- What happens if you enter more than 10 characters?  You get a *buffer overrun*.  Buffer overruns have been used to exploit programs.  Luckily, C++ has safety features, such as `std::string` instead of char arrays to avoid this from happening.

Comment: @RyanFolks Not likely in modern OSes. But I think that was a real thing in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is undefined behavior in this piece of code.
Please take a look at the [cplusplus reference](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)

Example here of how bitshifts are working:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   int a = 1, b = 3;
   
   // a right now is 00000001
   // Left shifting it by 3 will make it 00001000, ie, 8
   a = a << 3;
   cout << a << endl;
   
   // Right shifting a by 2 will make it 00000010, ie, 2
   a = a >> 2;
   cout << a << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Which will output:

```
8
2
```